# What flag to be used if I've used variables declared at collection scope in tests?

Tags: command-line, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-newman

I've used variables at environment, gloabl & collection level scope in my tests. I'm aware of the flags to be used for environment & gloabl level scope i.e. -e & -g respectively.

I'm not able to find flag to be used to pass the collection level variables json file in command line to execute my postman automated tests in newman.

Please help me out.

Comment: There isn't one but also those variables are part of the collection file, they are not separately exportable.

Answer (score 0):

The collection-variables are part of the collection. They're suitable for driving tests in single-enviroments.
I'm using them very rarely and only collection-related for the inner logic of my scripts, that is not environment related (e.g. constants as ISO-Codes).

If it becomes necessary to drive the same collection in different configs, i shift my variables to globals or env variables, depending on the use-case.

You can finde more details about this topic in
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#variable-scopes